# Mapping AD groups to roles without custom role provider (.NET MVC)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis, authorization, user-roles

I'm looking for a simple and intuitive (for future maintainers) way to map Active Directory groups to roles/permissions in my ASP.NET MVC application that uses Windows Auth.
Similar to this question [ASP.NET MVC Roles without database (and without role provider)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1304603/asp-net-mvc-roles-without-database-and-without-role-provider) but since that question was asked eight years ago, there may be new answers.

- I want to define certain roles in my application. (i.e. reader and editor)
- I want to use
  windows authentication.
- I want to map users and/or groups to those
  roles using only configuration.
- I do not want any dependencies
  between role names in my application and active directory group
  names.
- I would prefer not to code my own role provider or introduce
  third party components. (I could write one easily, but that adds to
  later maintanance)

I actually expected this to be straight forward, but I'm drawing a blank searching. Is there an easier solution than to implement a custom role provider?

I would like something that would lead to a config file conceptually like this:

```
<configuration>
<system.web>
      <authorization>
        <role name="Reader">
            <add users="bob"/>
            <add users="mydomain\My app readergroup"/>
        </role>
        <role name="Editor">
            <add users="alice"/>
            <add users="mydomain\My app editorgroup"/>
        </role>
        <allow roles="Reader, Editor"/>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up taking a simpler route. 
I defined local groups, assigned authorization to them and made the domain groups members of the local groups in production.